# jQuery hide() and show() not immediately run when reversed later in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` functions to show a loading message while a potentially long synchronous webservice call executes.

When clicking the button in the below snippet, I would expect the text "Some data" to be immediately replaced with "Loading..." and then go back to "Some other data" after 5 seconds.

As you can see, that is not what happens:

```js
function run_test() {
    $('#test1').hide();
    $('#test2').show();
    
    long_synchronous_function_call()
    
    $('#test2').hide();
    $('#test1').show();
}

function long_synchronous_function_call() {
    $('#test1').html('<p>Some other data</p>');
    var date = new Date();
 while ((new Date()) - date <= 5000) {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
    <p>Some data</p>
</div>

<div id="test2" style="display:none">
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>

<button onclick="run_test()">Call a long synchronous function!</button>
```

In fact, the "Loading" element never appears, and "Some other data" is simply replaced without our hypothetical user getting any feedback during the long wait.

What can I do to ensure that jQuery hides and shows my elements *now*, not once all my functions have finished executing?

Comment: *"a potentially long synchronous webservice call executes"* : this smells *very* bad. Do you really mean you call external services synchronously ? This must be seen as a bug today.

Comment: Async calls would return immediately and the result later via callback or promise. Your example is a synchronous wait loop, which will not work.

Comment: @dystroy - yes, I'm aware it's bad, but it's not something I'm able to change. If I could have, I'd have fixed the problem by making that function async long before I came here.

Comment: "Legacy" is one thing, but leaving code like `while ((new Date()) - date <= 5000) {}`, which will just lock up the browser, has to be avoided at all costs. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - that's just an example to demonstrate the problem. I'm not actually calling a webservice that just sleeps for 5 seconds then returns nothing - it's something a lot more complex than that. I wanted to demonstrate the issue I was having in the simplest way possible.

Comment: That was assumed, but not a great substitute. What does the real code look like? Why is it impossible to make it async?

Comment: It's not impossible. It's just not an option right now because it's a big job and there isn't the will to change things from my superiors. To be clear, I'm calling a codegen'd function, which exposes webmethods of a .asmx file. That codegen also produces code for several hundred other webmethods, so I'd have to change + test all of those, and all their calling code, if I was to make this call async. Again, I'd love to do it, but I'd have to do it for free, because my employers aren't gonna pay me for spending time on that right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The screen won't be rendered until your code stops execution. This is almost always the desired behavior, as it prevents the rendering of the DOM in an inconsistent state.

Supposing you *really* need to run a long synchronous task, and you can fix that or defer it to a [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), then a solution is to use `setTimeout`:

```js
function run_test() {
    $('#test1').hide();
    $('#test2').show();
    
    setTimeout(function(){
       long_synchronous_function_call()
    
       $('#test2').hide();
       $('#test1').show();
    },0);
}

function long_synchronous_function_call() {
    $('#test1').html('<p>Some other data</p>');
    var date = new Date();
 while ((new Date()) - date <= 5000) {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
    <p>Some data</p>
</div>

<div id="test2" style="display:none">
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>

<button onclick="run_test()">Call a long synchronous function!</button>
```

Just to be sure I'm not helping you hiding a bug: **NEVER do synchronous ajax calls**.

It **is** reasonable to do what I suggest when you really have a legitimate and somewhat long synchronous operation happening in your browser, though (for example a computation or the building of a complex GUI).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Of course it was, I want the rendering to happen before the execution starts (and locks everything).

Comment: Okay, but that example is a little crazy as the example code is synchronous.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, I suspect OP did something bad, and I try to make it clear in comments

Comment: I think you missed my point. You should not start an synchronous operation on the next frame to work-around this issue and their code (or your fix) will still not run correctly as you can't do in-line waits for a timeout: e.g. this is broken `while ((new Date()) - date <= 5000) {}`. You should use callbacks or promises and make it a real async function, then the problem goes away. See my answer for what I mean.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The discussion is a little void as we're probably on an XY problem but the question still is about how to render before a **synchronous** operation.

Comment: It *is* an XY as the question is approaching the problem incorrectly, but if you take the question literally, as you have, how do you expect the wait loop to work? e.g. `while ((new Date()) - date <= 5000) {}`. That will just hang the browser :)

Comment: Thanks, and don't worry about hiding bugs. If I was writing that function today, it wouldn't be synchronous. Alas, I'm not, and it's not trivial to change - such is the world of legacy code :(

Comment: @Hecksa I'll let the words of warning for other users coming later ;)