# DOM changes not executing immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I have a hidden element, I want to show it and then trigger an alert right after.

I tried using jquery:

```
$('#myElement').show();
alert('test');
```

I also tried using just regular javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').setStyle('display: block');
alert('test');
```

However in both cases I see that when I run this, the alert appears, my element is still not visible, and then once I close the alert then the element begins to show.

Why is the alert being run before the DOM is updated? Do I have any way to force a DOM update or do i need to add a manual timeout after I show the element?

I have tried playing around with $.then() and $.done() but neither seems to work.

Comment: Do **not** use `alert()` for debugging. You get into exactly this kind of situation where the solution isn't "how do I make the update before `alert`" but to just use `console.log` or even an actual debugger. `alert` blocks the UI thread, so the event loop will not finish, thus you don't get the updated page representation.

Comment: Okay. I don't know the whole story, but let me guess: do you wait until the page is ready (jQuery event) or some other event that guaranties that the page is loaded. If not than this could be an issue.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188845/jquery-hide-and-show-not-immediately-run-when-reversed-later-in-the-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browser repaints triggered by JS run on the main JavaScript event loop.

The DOM is updating, but the rendering of it isn't done until JS isn't busy with something else.

The `alert()` is blocking, so all JS on the main event loop is paused until it is dismissed.

You could wait for an animation frame before running your alert.

```
document.getElementById('myElement').setStyle('display: block');
requestAnimationFrame(() => alert('test');)
```

Comment: I always forget `requestAnimationFrame()` :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `alert()` is a modal operation which blocks the UI thread of the browser from updating. In the code above, when you call `alert()` the DOM is still in the process of being updated, but has not yet finished being redrawn, yet the thread has been blocked from completing until the user dismisses the `alert()`.

You have three solutions. Firstly you could put the `alert()` in a timeout to delay it:

```
$('#myElement').show();
setTimeout(function(){
  alert('test');
}, 20); // 20ms should be a long enough delay even on the slowest machines
```

Secondly, you could use a library to display non-modal alerts within the DOM itself, ie. [Notify](https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/).

Lastly, assuming your purpose is just for testing/debuggin, you can use `console.log()` as it does not a modal operation:

```
$('#myElement').show();
console.log('test');
```

To see the console, press <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser. Note that this method, along with `console.dir()`, should always be used for debugging, not `alert()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery, then you can add an callback after `show()` is executed.

Link for document: http://api.jquery.com/show/

```
$('#myElement').show(400, function() {
   alert('test')
})
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but note that this is not the same logic as the OP originally had. By providing a duration to `show()` you're creating an animation (a fade effect by default).